# Head tracking stuttering/lag/blur issue with Google Carboard

Tags: unity, virtual-reality

I am working on Virtual Reality app. I have created a city terrain and when I move around the terrain using keyboard it move smoothly but when using head tracking I feel a lag/blur when I move or look around the scene using Google Cardboard. How can I improve the performance.Is there any method in unity?